# Vue CLI no longer asks a for feature selection

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

When creating a new Vue (2.x) project using Vue CLI v4 with the command:

```sh
vue create example
```

...I should be prompted for selecting which features I'd like to enable. For some reason, the CLI jumps straight to creating the project, presumably with features I've selected before.

How can I get the cli to let me specify features again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems your Vue CLI installation is somehow toasted.

As the first fix attempt I'd try deleting the file `.vuerc` file in your user home directory (`~/.vuerc`) where Vue CLI stores the saved presets.

If that doesn't help, I'd recommend reinstalling the Vue CLI package globally:

#### Steps to reinstall Vue CLI globally

```sh
# If Vue CLI is installed globally, remove the installation

# Check globally installed packages list with NPM
npm list -g --depth 0
# OR with Yarn
yarn global ls

# Depending on which package manager it has been installed with
# Uninstall with NPM
npm uninstall -g @vue/cli
# OR with Yarn
yarn global remove @vue/cli

# Install currently newest Vue CLI version with NPM
npm install -g @vue/cli
# OR with Yarn
yarn global add @vue/cli
```

Comment: I'm actually using @vue/cli 4.0.5.  One of my issues is that I can't choose anymore whether to use yarn or npm, which I was able to select at one point.

Comment: Aha, I've just submitted edits to your question clarifying the versions used...just a moment I will edit this answer also.

Comment: Thanks for the bounty David J! If this solved your problem, could you also mark this answer as the accepted answer?

Comment: Of course, just overlooked that.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your project set prompt=false and use JSON to create projects. As far as I know, you should set prompt=true or for each project use should use:

```
vue create example --default
```

This should prompt features (>manually select features).

In Vue's Documentation, you can find the create project options [creating projects with Vue](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/creating-a-project.html#vue-create)

In Reactgo page, they showed some features of project creation process [How to create Vue project](https://reactgo.com/vue-cli3-tutorial-creating-project/)

Comment: Doing this actually resulted in automatically creating a project without any options to select

Comment: Using `--default` on the command actually ensures that the installed doesn't ever prompt for feature selection, instead selecting the default values.

Comment: Do you use windows? If so, I found a warning: "If you are on Windows using Git Bash with minTTY, the interactive prompts will not work. You must launch the command as ```winpty vue.cmd create newProject```." In order to, show prompt on a windows machine, you should run create command referred as above.

Comment: @furkanayd  I use Windows 10 but with powershell, not git bash.

Answer (score 0):

The issue for me was that I was using Git Bash to `vue create app-name` instead of Windows CMD.

Once I re-ran the command in Windows CMD the Vue feature selection worked properly.